# java -jar classpath refers jar inside ear

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, ear

I have one big app.ear file which contains all my jar. now i am having another healthcheck.jar which will check the database up or not by connecting to database. now database client is inside the ear file, again i don't want to put the client jars(database client, hibernates jars etc) into healthcheck.jar.

is their a way so that i can exclude packaging database client jar from healthcheck.jar and refer it while run time from inside app.ear i'e

```
java -jar healthcheck.jar -classpath app.ear/hibernate.jar
```

Both are stored in common folder.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of bundling in the jar file you could add app1jar.jar as an endorsed jar to the container. It's then available to all installed apps.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13706/libraries.htm#WLPRG332

Comment: but the problem is i am getting this ear from other third party. i cant modify it